# Sign-in link in custom master page

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm learning site and page building with Liferay DXP 7.4 using theme books, custom master page and so on.

Even after extensive searching I could not find how to use the default login link (login portlet opening the login popup) in my custom master page.

I can just embed the popup content itself (widgets / tools / sign in, which is the comlete login form) but not the link as used in the default theme (and this page header code is read only, so I cannot analyze it).

Any hints how to use the sign in link (not the form) in a custom master page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, created a Fragment with special Freemarker Syntax ([] instead of <>) and used it in master page template.

```
<div class="fragment_101">
    [@liferay.user_personal_bar /]
</div>
```